# Como fazer um botão de rollback ou "undo" na minha aplicação?

Tags: php, mysql

Existe alguma forma de recuperar os dados deletados do Banco de Dados? Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde tenho os botôes de adicionar, editar e deletar e agora estou pensando em fazer outro de desfazer um delete. Como posso fazer isso? Acredito que existem diversas maneiras, poderiam citar algumas?

```
<?php 

require_once '../core/init.php';
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
//Get Brands database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM frutas ORDER BY frutas";
$results = $db->query($sql);
$errors = array();

//Editar
if(isset($_GET['edit']) && !empty($_GET['edit'])){
    $edit_id = (int)$_GET['edit'];
    $edit_id = sanitize($edit_id);
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM frutas WHERE id = '$edit_id'";
    $edit_result = $db->query($sql2);
    $eBrand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit_result);

}

//Deletar
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){
    $delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete'];
    $delete_id = sanitize($delete_id);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM frutas WHERE id = '$delete_id'";
    $db->query($sql);
    header('Location: frutas.php');

}
//Se 'adicionar' for submetido
if(isset($_POST['add_submit'])){
    $frutas = sanitize($_POST['frutas']);
    //Checkar espaços em branco
    if($_POST['frutas'] == ''){
        $errors[] .= 'Adiciona alguma fruta!';
    }
    // Checar se alguma fruta existe no banco de dados
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM frutas WHERE frutas = '$frutas'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count > 0){
        $errors[] .= $frutas.' Já existe. Adicione outra.';
    }
    //Mostrar erros
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        echo display_errors($errors);
    }else{
        //Adicionar frutas no banco de dados
        $sql = "INSERT INTO frutas (frutas) VALUES ('$frutas')";
        $db->query($sql);
        header('Location: frutas.php');
    }
}

?>

<h2 class="text-center">PHP na feira da Fruta</h2><hr>
<!--Fruta form-->
<div class="text-center">
 <form class="form-inline" action="frutas.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="frutas">Adicionar Fruta:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frutas" id="frutas" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['frutas']))?$_POST['frutas']:''); ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="add_submit" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
 </form>    
</div><hr>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-auto table-condensed" style="margin: 0 auto; width: auto;">
    <thead>
        <th></th><th>Frutas</th><th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while($frutas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="frutas.php?edit=<?=$frutas['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sc btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
            <td><?=$frutas['frutas'] ?></td>
            <td><a href="frutas.php?delete=<?=$frutas['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sc btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</br>
<center><input type="submit" name="add_submit" value="DESFAZER DELETE" class="btn btn-success"></center>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

O `DELETE` não pode ser desfeito diretamente, exceto se estiver numa [`TRANSACTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), neste caso poderia utilizar o `ROLLBACK` *(usando o `mysqli_rollback($conexao)`)*;

**Entretanto não é isso que você deseja**, você deseja excluir e depois o usuário consiga restaurar os dados numa nova requisição.

Para isso o melhor a se fazer, ou mais fácil, é usar `UPDATE`, crie uma coluna de `Deletado` com o padrão de `0` e então utilize ela para identificar se um item está ou não deletado.

```
mysqli_query($conexao, 'UPDATE SET Deletado = 1 WHERE id = 1');
```

Depois para "recuperar" utilize:

```
mysqli_query($conexao, 'UPDATE SET Deletado = 0 WHERE id = 1');
```

Dessa forma o item será "recuperado" uma vez que sua aplicação sempre utilizará o `Deletado` como base. Por essa razão deverá utilizar um `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE Deletado = 0` para saber que o item não está deletado.

Você também pode criar um `DataDeletado` para saber a data que o item foi deletado, assim poderá criar um "cronjob" (ou o [`Scheduled Events`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)) para deletar de fato (executando `DELETE`) naquilo que for antigo, assim poderá permitir que o usuário recupere um dado em até 10 minutos e depois disso a informação realmente será apagada.

Uma outra opção é criar um outro banco/tabela e mover os dados "excluídos" para lá, de maneira temporária ou permanente, depois para "recuperar" copie para o local de origem.

Comment: Como assim padrão de 0? E no "id = 1" esse id seria o da fruta?

Comment: O `id` seria o `id` que deseja excluir, no caso `id = '$delete_id'` por exemplo, normalmente. O padrão do `Deletado` deve ser, neste caso, `0`. Dessa forma todos os elementos futuramente criados (e já criados)  serão `0`. Por exemplo `ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN Deletado TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;`, dessa forma irá criar uma coluna na `tabela` sendo `tinyint` com padrão de `0`. Se estiver usando algum PHPMyAdmin ou HeidiSQL, eles permitem criar um valor padrão, então basta criar uma coluna `Deletado` com o padrão `0`, sendo `INT` ou `TINYINT`.